# JUnit cannot find ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

So was using a tutorial here https://hop2croft.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/jpa-basic-example-with-entitymanager-spring-and-maven/ and I keep getting an error when I run as a JUnit test saying it can't find application context. The test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/testApplicationContext.xml")
public class CarTest {
```

is this and I tried putting the testapplicationcontext.xml in like every folder so far. It used to be

```
 @ContextConfiguration(locations={"/testApplicationContext.xml"}) but I thought if I change it, it might fix it.
```

Any suggestions?

Its currently in a new folder I had to make, srcs/test/resources. I created this project from scratch in eclipse with STS.

Edit: At the end of the chain I followed in the console I got

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
```

Also here is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.hopcroft.examples.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>simpledao</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-annotation</id>
        <url>http://maven-annotation-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>



  <repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>JBoss Deprecated</id>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated</url>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>java.net</id>
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
  <build>
        <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>




        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated-java</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/generated-java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
                 </pluginManagement>

</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.openxma</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsl-platform</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: try `/src/test/resources`.

Comment: prefix with `classpath:`.

Answer (score 1):

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/testApplicationContext.xml")
public class CarTest {

...}